# How to AutoFit excel column using OpenXML Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, visual-studio-2012, openxml

This code to generate Excel spreadsheet Using openxml package. Please anyone tell how to auto fit its column width.

```
OpenXmlPackage.SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = OpenXmlPackage.SpreadsheetDocument.Create(downloadFilePath, OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
// Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
OpenXmlPackage.WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
// Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
workbookpart.Workbook = new OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Workbook();
int numDates = datesObject.Length;

// Add Sheets to the Workbook.
OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Sheets sheets = new OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Sheets();
OpenXml.UInt32Value sheetId = 1;

OpenXmlPackage.WorksheetPart firstWorksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<OpenXmlPackage.WorksheetPart>();
firstWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Worksheet(new OpenXmlSpreadsheet.SheetData());
// Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Sheet firstSheet = new OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(firstWorksheetPart), SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Summary" };
sheets.Append(firstSheet);
sheetId++;

 OpenXmlSpreadsheet.SheetData firstSheetData = firstWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<OpenXmlSpreadsheet.SheetData>();

 DataTable summaryTable = new DataTable();
 summaryTable.Clear();
 summaryTable.Columns.Add("name");
 summaryTable.Columns.Add("value");

 DataRow _summaryInfo = summaryTable.NewRow();
 _summaryInfo["name"] = "Clinic Name";
 _summaryInfo["value"] = userInfo[0];
 summaryTable.Rows.Add(_summaryInfo);



 int firstRowCount = summaryTable.Rows.Count;

 for (int rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= firstRowCount; rowNumber++)
 {
      DataRow dataRow = summaryTable.Rows[rowNumber - 1];
      OpenXmlSpreadsheet.Row contentRow = ExcelHandler.createContentRow(dataRow, rowNumber);
      firstSheetData.AppendChild(contentRow);
 }

 firstWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The auto-fit logic is something which is implemented by Microsoft Excel, and is not a part of the OpenXML spreadsheet format. Auto-fit involves measuring the width (or height) of the value in each cell and finding the maximum value.

In order to implement auto-fit in your own code, you will have to manually measure the text; you can use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` or `Graphics.MeasureString` with appropriate format flags (disable prefix characters). This will give you a size in pixels, which you will need to convert to Excel's convoluted column width units. The formula for this is:

width = Truncate([{Number of Characters} * {Maximum Digit Width} + {5 pixel padding}]/{Maximum Digit Width}*256)/256

Taken from this article: [Column Class (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column(v=office.14).aspx)

(Maximum Digit Width can be determined by measuring the width of the `'0'` character using the workbook's default font - told you it was convoluted!)

Once you have obtained the cell widths using this formula, you can find the maximum value and apply it to the `Column.Width` property.

There are subtle differences in the way Microsoft Excel renders text (compared to how GDI/GDI+ does it), so this method is not 100% accurate - but it is sufficient for most purposes and you can always add some extra padding to ensure a proper fit.

Comment: What does the `Truncate` exactly do and why is it needed?

Comment: @Emaborsa `Truncate` discards the decimal portion of the number, effectively rounding it down to the nearest integer. This is needed because pixels are expressed as whole numbers.

Comment: OK, but the `Column.Width` property takes a `double` (I think in points) and not an `int` for the pixel...

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was wrong; the `Column.Width` property is measured in Excel's column width units (not pixels or points). So the `Truncate` function is used purely because Microsoft decided to discard the decimal portion of the result before dividing by 256 - maybe this is for precision reasons? Anyway, it does not make a huge difference to the final figure.

Comment: @Prakash Gupta take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612337/openxml-change-excel-cell-format-date-and-number-when-exporting-from-datagri/55692946#55692946). Posted code is in DOM method, but I created a solution with SAX approach too and results are outstanding - no memory drain (writing directly from DataReader) and much faster than Interop library. Only down-side is Autofit - you ave to read same data twice.