# Auto width of column and word wrap of Headers not working in OpenXML Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

While I'm trying to open excel file using OpenXML. Excel is coming fine but my style property is not taking.

1. I need to give my excel data column has auto width property.I found this solution but its not working for me

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268620/openxml-auto-size-column- 
   width- 
   in-excel
   ```

2.I am not able to word-wrap my column headers but values getting wrapped

below is my excel code having the width property to set

```
 public static string OpenXMLCreateXL(string FolderPath, DataSet tableSet)
 {
 WorkbookPart wBookPart = null;
 var datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_");
  string FilePath = "";
   foreach (DataTable table1 in tableSet.Tables)
  {
 if (table1.Rows.Count != 0)
 {
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(FilePath, 
SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
 wBookPart = spreadsheetDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
wBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
uint sheetId = 1;
spreadsheetDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild();
WorkbookStylesPart wbsp = wBookPart.AddNewPart();
wbsp.Stylesheet = CreateStylesheet();
wbsp.Stylesheet.Save();
 foreach (DataTable table in tableSet.Tables)
 {
 if (table.Rows.Count != 0)
 {
 table.TableName = table.Rows[0]["LeaseCondition"].ToString();
 WorksheetPart wSheetPart = wBookPart.AddNewPart();
 Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wSheetPart), SheetId = 
sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
sheets.Append(sheet);
SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
wSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
Row headerRow = new Row();
Columns columns = new Columns();
int ColumnNumber = 1;
  foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
 {
   Cell cell = new Cell();
     cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
    cell.StyleIndex = 2;
    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
    Column column1 = new Column();  
     column1.Width = 30; ;
   column1.BestFit = true;
    column1.CustomWidth = true;        //how i can set autowidth here?
   column1.Min = Convert.ToUInt32(ColumnNumber);
  column1.Max = Convert.ToUInt32(ColumnNumber);
  columns.AppendChild(column1);
   ColumnNumber = ColumnNumber + 1;
    }
     wSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(columns);
     sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);
     foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
   Row row = new Row();
  foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
     {
  Cell cell = new Cell();
   cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
  cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dr[column].ToString());
   cell.StyleIndex = 1;
  row.AppendChild(cell);
}
sheetData.AppendChild(row);
  }
   sheetId++;
  wSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(sheetData);
    }
    }
  }
  }
    }
     return FilePath;
     }
```

My word wrap code

```
       Alignment alignment0 = new Alignment();
        alignment0.WrapText = true;
        alignment0.Vertical = VerticalAlignmentValues.Top;
       

        CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats(
                new CellFormat(new Alignment() { WrapText = true }), // default
                new CellFormat { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 
      1,ApplyBorder = true, Alignment = alignment0, ApplyAlignment = true }, // 
     body
                new CellFormat { FontId = 1, FillId = 2, BorderId = 1, ApplyFill 
       = true ,ApplyAlignment = true,} // header
            );
```

any help or suggestions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble creating OpenXml documents then the [Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425) can be very useful - it will let you see what you are actually creating, or allow you to examine a doc created in Excel (or other suitable app).

One point that initially caught me out when I was doing the same sort of work was that the order of elements in the XML matters, make sure you add parts in the right order - look at a working example if in doubt.

Comment: That's a different question entirely :) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197038/how-to-autofit-excel-column-using-openxml-package for starters.